# Importing a Room database programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

For exporting room database as backup file I'm calling method `RoomDatabase.close()` because when you close database it merges all db files `.db-wal`, `.db-shm` into one `MyApp.db` file I use this code to export MyApp.db file to external storage:

```
try {
    val dbFile = File(databasePath)
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(dbFile)
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)

    while (true) {
        val length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)
        if (length <= 0)
            break
        outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION WHILE WRITING DATABASE TO BACKUP", e)
}
```

this peace of code executes correctly and exports database, then I use code below to import database it takes exported `MyApp.db` file and replaces currently used db, but in app it shows empty database even if I reopen the app, I'm guessing its because when I'm importing database it imports just this one db file MyApp.db, but its missing `.db-wal` and `.db-shm` How can I extract these files from .db? And I'm I doing it right?

```
try {
    val parcelFileDescription = contents.parcelFileDescriptor
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescription.fileDescriptor)

    val output = FileOutputStream(dbPath)

    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)

    while (true) {
        val length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)
        if (length <= 0)
            break
        output.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }

    output.flush()
    output.close()
    fileInputStream.close()
    Toast.makeText(context, "Import completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("TAGAS", "EXCEPTION: ", e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is it repeatedly overwrites at the same location in the output file `output.write(buffer, 0, length)`. Replace the 0 with an index var:

```
var index = 0
while (true) {
    val length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)
    if (length <= 0)
        break
    output.write(buffer, index, length)
    index += length
}
```